# git merge says 'Already up-to-date.' but isn't

Tags: git

i have some branches test, production and dev. I want to merge the dev branch into the test branch.

I tried with git merge dev (from test branch). Git says its up-to-date but it isn't! After adding a comment in one of the files and delete the comment and another try with git merge it works -.- For thie special file git shows ALL modifications (not only the "ghost" comment) and merges correct.

What ist my mistake here? I can't see anything wrong....

Greetings

Comment: Is your test branch created on top of dev?

Comment: Do you always do `git add yourfilehere && git commit -m "Test update"` before merging? Are your changes tracked? Did you actually check out the relevant branches?

Comment: No it's not. That's what i thought first :) I should have said that, sorry.

Comment: Everything is tracked and commitet. I realy don't know whats going on there

Comment: @derfmt could you post an image of your commit history from something like SourceTree or GitKraken?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely candidates are:

- Your local repository is not up to date yet
- You are merging with a local branch that is not up to date yet

Either way you can probably fix this by performing:

```
git pull
git merge origin/<the branch you want>
```

If not I would like more information.